# Ms Access VBA Date filter

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I'm self studying a VBA code, I got one question.
Hope can get your help.

Here is my situation:

I've 15 records in the table, they're date value like: 
31 Jan 2016, 29 Feb 2016, 30 Nov 2016, 31 Dec 2016
the field name is [dayTo]

And I've two Forms,
1st Form = "F_temp", a txt box "date0" in this form.
2nd Form = "F_visitorRec", this form will show the record from [dayTo]

I'd like to made a openForm with condition like:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_visitorRec", acNormal, , "[dayTo] >= #" & Me![date0] & "#"
```

But I never success, if I input 01 Nov 2016, it will show all 15 record.
If I input 09 Nov 2016, it will show the date large than September.
If I input 13 Nov 2016, the result is correct, 
it can show the record lager than 13 Nov 2016.
I know this problem should related to the date format, but I try many method but still can't fix.

Hope can get your help.

Comment: What is the data type of your table date? It is always best to refer to dates as year-month-day.

Comment: Thanks ! I've set the field, txt box, query format to yyyy/mmm/dd. But still not work. Gustav's ans is work. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Apply a proper format to the string expression for the date value:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_visitorRec", acNormal, , "[dayTo] >= #" & Format(Me![date0].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! Gustav ! <br/> But which format I should choose in the field, txt box, query ? or just leave it blank ?

Comment: I've try following but why didn't work.  <br/> Dim date0 As String
date0 = Format(Date, "dd\mmmm\yyyy")

Comment: Typically, you set the _Format_ property to _Short Date_ or _Long Date_.